# Update(reassociate) lookups on newly created object from an old object

Tags: apex, list, clone

What is a better way of writing the below code so I can avoid repeating similar lines of code for every lookup object that I try to re associate
Here Speaker & Session are Lookups on Event Object, I have other lookup fields as well that are on the Event object where I am trying to update the values from older Event to newly created Event

```
List<Speaker__c> speaker = new List<Speaker__c>();

    for (Speaker__c speakerInfo:[Select Id, Event__c FROM Speaker__c where Event__c =: oldEvent.Id]) {
    speakerInfo.Event__c = insertEvent[0].Id;
    speaker.add(speakerInfo);
    }

    if (!speaker.isEmpty()) {
    update speaker;
    }

    List<Session__c> session = new List<Session__c>();

    for (Session__c sessionInfo:[Select Id, Event__c FROM Session__c where Event__c =: oldEvent.Id]) {
    sessionInfo.Event__c = insertEvent[0].Id;
    session.add(sessionInfo);
    }

    if (!session.isEmpty()) {
    update session;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this in seven lines of code:

```
sObject[] recordsToUpdate = new sObject[0];
recordsToUpdate.addAll([SELECT Id FROM Speaker__c WHERE Event__c = :oldEvent.Id]);
recordsToUpdate.addAll([SELECT Id FROM Session__c WHERE Event__c = :oldEvent.Id]);
for(sObject record: recordsToUpdate) {
    record.put('Event__c', insertEvent[0].Id);
}
update recordsToUpdate;
```

We use sObject to create a list of heterogenous records that can be updated all at once, and then use [Dynamic Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic.htm) to set the fields, all in one loop. Without context, I don't know if this needs to be bulkified, etc, but you can certainly make the code more compact.

Note that "empty list" guards are not necessary; a DML on an empty list is a "no-op" (it does nothing and doesn't count against governor limits).

Also, you don't need to query fields you don't need to read from (e.g. the Event__c field is not necessary in your code).